# Is it possible to allocate fixed amount of storage to members in an iCloud Family?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

I want to setup a Family plan on the new Apple One offering. At the time of writing this, Apple includes 200GB storage on the basic family plan, but this is shared among all members of the family. Is there a way to allocate a fixed amount of storage to each user?

I'd like to set it up and then have my parents use the iCloud storage to backup their iPhones, while my sister and I will probably use it for backups and file storage. The problem is, if I don't allocate each member 50GB, one person will end up using more than their fair share of storage, and you know that will just end in a big fight.

If this is not possible, is the alternative possible:

Can each of the members of the family get their own subscription for a 50GB plan, but then have that billed through to my account as the organizer of the family? That way I'll still pay for their storage, like I offered to do, but the subscription is on their account and therefore no fighting over storage?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot allocate storage from the shared pool. However:

If each member gets their own 50GB but you have a shared payment method specified (do you pay for applications they purchase? if so then you have this turned on) then all the iCloud Storage bills will go straight to you.

My recommendation is to try sharing 200GB first - if you've already tried this (your writing seems to indicate you haven't) or if it immediately fails then you could split it up - but you may be overestimating how much any individual person's storage will grow based on what's available.